Vert.x OpenAPI v4.5.10 ValidatorException: "The related request does not contain the required body" for POST request
I'm working with Vert.x and OpenAPI to create an HTTP server, and I'm encountering a ValidatorException when handling a request with a required body. Specifically, the error message is: The related request does not contain the required body.
public void start() {
    String pathContract = "./api.yaml";
    contract = OpenAPIContract.from(vertx , pathContract);

    contract.onSuccess(contractRes -> {
        routerBuilder = RouterBuilder.create(vertx, contractRes , RequestExtractor.withBodyHandler());

        requestValidator = RequestValidator.create(vertx , contractRes);
        responseValidator = ResponseValidator.create(vertx , contractRes);

        routerBuilder.getRoute("addUser").addHandler(this::addUser);
        router = routerBuilder.createRouter();

        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(8000 , res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("server is running");
            } else {
                System.out.println("error " + res.cause());
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Validator created successfully.");
    }).onFailure(error -> {
        System.out.println("Failed to load OpenAPI contract: " + error.getMessage());
    });
}

public void addUser(RoutingContext ctx) {
    requestValidator.validate(ctx.request(), "addUser").onSuccess(validatedRequest -> {
        JsonObject bodyData = validatedRequest.getBody().getJsonObject();
        String name = bodyData.getString("name");

        if (!name.isEmpty()) {
            ctx.response().end("name is : " + name);
        } else {
            ctx.response().end("error " + name);
        }
    }).onFailure(err -> {
        ctx.response().setStatusCode(400).end("error " + err.getMessage());
    });
}


yaml :
  /user :
    post:
      summary : Add a new user
      operationId: addUser
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                name:
                  type: string
      responses:
        '201':
          description : user created

When I disable validation with route.setDoValidation(false), the request works without errors.
route.setDoValidation(false);

I tried to set up request validation for a POST route (/addUser) in Vert.x OpenAPI v4.5.10, following the OpenAPI definition in api.yaml. I expected the validator to confirm the presence and structure of the required JSON body.
Instead, I received a ValidatorException stating "The related request does not contain the required body." However, when I disable validation with route.setDoValidation(false), the route works as expected, but this bypasses validation, which I need active to check the body structure.

It's a bit confusing. When I bring down vertx-web-openapi 4.5.10 from maven central (according to maven coordinates given on their web site) there is no OpenAPIContract class in the jar. And the package naming in the jar is different from the naming in the eclipse-vertx/vertx-web-openapi  github repo. Is vertx still a viable alternative?

The issue occurs because Vert.x needs a body handler to extract the request body before validation.
routerBuilder.rootHandler(BodyHandler.create());

